# reset index value to zero onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

It's really in the question, but, how can I reset the value of the index to zero onclick?

I have a list of videos, where any of them can be played by clicking on them. Once the video has completed, it will play the next video.

It works, but if you click one and then another, instead of playing the next video onend, it will play the video two after the one that just played. If you click a third time, the third one will be played. I understand that it's because the function is called on `ended` and that each time you click a new video to play, the previous one ends, and adds to its value.

How do I make it stop doing this?

The function for playing the next video is:

```
$("#myVid").bind("ended", function() {
            $("#bigPic").removeClass("move");
            $("#MyT").fadeIn(250);
            function playArray(ele, array) {
                index++;
                if (index >= array.length) {
                    index = i;
                }
                ele.src = array[index];
                ele.load();
                ele.play();
            }
            playArray(document.getElementById("myVid"), videos);
        });
```

p.s. I've tried to reduce the value by adding `index--` onclick, but that just looped the video.

Comment: try widening the scope of the variable `index` and explicitly setting it's value to `0` inside the click handler ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are saving your videolist in an array, right?! so there are two actions: 1. user clicks on a video, so your index should be your selected one 2. video is on end, jump to next in list if exist.

```
var index = 0;

$("YourVideoList").bind("click", function() {
   index = "yourCurrentSelectedItem"     
});

$("#myVid").bind("ended", function() {
        $("#bigPic").removeClass("move");
        $("#MyT").fadeIn(250);
        function playArray(ele, array) {
            index++;
            if (index >= array.length) {
                index = 0;   //replaced "i" with 0, to play first video in list
                //return;    //break, if you want the list to stop at the end of the last video
            }
            ele.src = array[index];
            ele.load();
            ele.play();
        }
        playArray(document.getElementById("myVid"), videos);
    });
```

that should do it!

Comment: I know it should do it, but it doesn't. if you click around to choose a video, and then watch, it goes crazy...

Comment: it goes crazy is a real precise description ;) maybe you should clear the sources of your videotag before setting new one? maybe this link helps (html5 video playlist with php)  http://www.bionicworks.com/php/generate-a-playlist-for-html5-video

Comment: sorry, but the videos start playing very oddly. current->current->first->third is what happened one time, for example. and i'll take a look